Combinatorics book recommendations for pure mathematics.
I'm looking for a textbook recommendation for a first course in combinatorics that is purely focused on theoretical mathematics. Most of the books I've come across tend to have a significant emphasis on computer science or various applications, but I'm specifically interested in a text that delves into the foundational theory without any practical applications.

I familiar with Linear algebra, Real analysis, ODE, Calculus and Complex analysis. I also done many rigorous proofs so I am familiar with rigorous math books. Are there any prerequisites that I need?

Whether this is appropriate for a "first course" depends on what you mean by that term, but Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics is extremely comprehensive: https://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/

What level are you looking for? What is the reader's mathematical sophistication? I liked Richard Stanley's "Enumerative Combinatorics," but it assumes some mathematical sophistication, up to and including some abstract algebra.

The other possibility is to look for older books - from the 1980s or earlier. Much less focused on applications, but maybe lacking in more modern approaches to things.

@ThomasAndrews I familiar with Linear algebra, Real analysis, ODE, calculus and Complex analysis.

Put it in the question. Linear algebra is some use, but abstract algebra would really help for the Stanley book. But the real question is whether you are accustomed to "theorem-proof" type books. All of those topics you listed can be taught either more intuitively or more rigorously. It is really an unmeasurable question of what we sometimes call "mathematical sophistication."

@ThomasAndrews Yes I am familiar with "theorem-proof" type books.

Check out this page by Jacob Lurie.

How do you define "combinatorial mathematics"? Opinions vary and it matters to answer your question properly.

@Somos: "How do you define "combinatorial mathematics"? Opinions vary and it matters to answer your question properly." Can you give me some options to see what do you mean.

Have you read the Wikipedia article on Combinatorics yet?

@Somos As far as I understand there are four different definitions, Can you give recommendations for each definition ?

quote from lecture1.pdf from the above linked Lurie course: "After canvassing some experts, I’ve come to the conclusion that there is no real consensus as to what should be taught in a course like this one." This might explain why there's not much standard textbooks for combinatorics

I recommend that you "follow your nose". Use the definition that appeals to you and aligns with what you want to learn from your studies.

When I was in university, we used the textbook:
Mathematics of choice
subtitled How to count without counting
by Ivan Niven.

Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics. https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Advanced_Combinatorics.html?id=C0HPgWhEssYC&redir_esc=y
Riordan, An Introduction to Combinatorial Analysis. https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691615882/an-introduction-to-combinatorial-analysis?srsltid=AfmBOoqC_N99tx863V7DILYf5jLqm4G7pHCgrNNt5ErSWKMpQKKIrW_2
Herbert John Ryser, Combinatorial Mathematics. https://www.ams.org/books/car/014/

Another selection that could be helpful:

Algebraic Combinatorics - Walks, Trees, Tableux, and More by R. P. Stanley

Counting: The Art of Enumerative Combinatorics by G. E. Martin

Discrete Mathematics - Elementary and Beyond by L. Lovasz,  J. Pelikan and K. Vesztergombi


Two more with special topics:

Classic Papers in Combinatorics by the editors Ira Gessel and Gian-Carlo Rota

Combinatorial Species and Tree-Like Structures by F. Bergeron, G. Labelle and P. Leroux



@Mathematicsenjoyer: Many thanks for granting the bounty. :-)
